# URL Rewrite in IIS on a Shared Hosting Server with Plesk as Hosting panel

Tags: iis, asp-classic, redirect

I am having a classic ASP application which demands URL Rewriting like below

mysite.com/product.asp?prid=100

must be written like this

mysite.com/product/100/

I dont have direct server access as I am on a shared server, Here they provide Plesk as hosting panel

Answer (score 0):

you need to set rule like this

```
<rule name="Rewrite to product">
    <match url="^product/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/product.asp?&amp;prid={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: On which file ? web.config ??